# Scope of class member within conditional if

Tags: c++, class, scope

In C++ I've created a class with a protected (data type) member and with a private (function) member:

```
class Qt3DViewer : public QMainWindow
{
 ...
 protected:
    vtkImageData * imgC1;
 ...
 private:
    void ComputeSlices();
}
```

In the implementation of the class member "ComputeSlices" I'm using a conditional `if` to update `imgC1`:

```
void Qt3DViewer::ComputeObliqueSlices()
{
 ...
 if (someFlag==1)
     this->imgC1 = reader1->GetOutput();
 else
     this->imgC1 = reader2->GetOutput();

 ...
 // Code that requires this->imgC1 updated!
}
```

The problem is that updating of `imgC1`is valid only within the conditional, after the if block updating goes out of scope and `imgC1` member is **NOT** really updated!

How can I update `imgC1`using a conditional block and ensure that after the block the member is actually updated?

Comment: By no means I'm a C++ expert, so I'm not sure if declaring `imgC1` as protected and `ComputeSlices`as private has something to do.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Of course `imgC1` is being updated, you're assigning a value to it in both branches of the conditional. After the conditional you can do whatever you want with `imgC1`. I don't quite understand what's the problem.

Comment: With this code changes done inside `if` block should reflect outside.. can you given an example with pointer values what you are observing?

Comment: Why dont you show the `Getoutput` functions too?

Comment: The debugger is your friend in a case like this! Set a breakpoint on the line with the `if`, and then step to see what happens. If the result is unexpected, then _step into_ the getter function to see what happens there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shown is valid unless

```
reader1->GetOutput();
```

returns a pointer to an local object, which would result in an **Undefined Behavior** & might show the behavior that you experience.

Something like:

```
vtkImageData *GetOutput()
{
    vtkImageData obj;
    //....
    //....
    //....
    vtkImageData* ptr = &obj;
    //....
    //....
    //....
    return ptr;
}
```

Note that, all class members irrespective of their access specfiers are accessible within the member functions of that class.
So unless, You have a Undefined Behavior lurking in your code, `this->imgC1` is always accessible and should be updated in the member function the way you are using it.

Comment: Thanks Als, that was actually the problem, class member GetOutput() was returning a pointer to a local object. I've circumvented the problem by avoiding using this method (in VTK). Thanks again.

Comment: @msotaquira: Glad my psychic debugging was correct :) However,You should fix the problem instead of using a workaround.The function `GetOutput()` has a bug and it should be fixed.It should either return a object by copy or it should return a dynamically allocated object whose ownership is transferred to the caller & owner frees the dynamic memory(by calling `delete`) once done with his work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with the reader1->GetOutput(), for example, some local object of the GetOutput() is released after the all of GetOutput()